# AngularJS: Apply filter to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I created a simple filter to format a number based on the current locale.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('doubleFilter', DoubleFilter);

function DoubleFilter($translate) {
    return function(val, decimalPlaces) {
        if (val && (typeof val === 'number')) {
            val = val.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
            if ($translate.use() === 'de_DE') {
                val = val.replace('.', ',');
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

};
```

I call this filter in my template like this and it works fine:

```
{{dog.weight | doubleFilter : 2}}
```

However when I change the language using $translate.use('en_US') the format of the numbers in my template are not updated. Obviously I am missing out on something here.

How can I update the view when the language changes?

Answer (score 1):

I think your directive needs to listen for 'local changed notification', for example :

```
scope.$on('$localeChangeSuccess', function () {
            // code to execute the filter
              });
```

Comment: Hi Tusahr, thanks for the reply. I am able to listen to the event now, however could you please elaborate a bit on "how to execute the filter"?

Comment: @Paul, add    scope.$digest() to execute your filter again

Answer (score 0):

Making your filter stateful may help ( see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter )